# Cross-origin problem: Google Customer Reviews is not displaying on success page

Tags: magento2, google

We've recently implemented Google's Customer Review module into our success page.

However, the console bugs. It keeps telling me:

```
jquery.js:2998 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://my-dev-domain.tld" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I understand that this is a problem from `CORS`, and therefore I added the following to my `.htaccess`:
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

However, this also didn't worked. The error is still showing.

Deactivating FPC hasn't changed something.

I've learned that there's a fix for `page-cache.js` in future versions of Magento (> 2.1.5, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/8005).

However, copying the new PR to the staging system doesn't resolve the error, it still bugs.

How could I now solve my problem?

Btw, this is the code I inject:

**In head**:

`https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn`

**In body**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          "merchant_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
          "order_id": "<?= $data['orderid']; ?>",
          "email": "<?= $data['email']; ?>",
          "delivery_country": "<?= $data['country_id']; ?>",
          "estimated_delivery_date": "<?= $data['delivery_date']; ?>"
        });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Basic:

- we are on Magento 2.0.4
- when trying to use my solution on a Magento 2.1.5 system nothing gets shown, nor is there an error in the console

Comment: Did you install on Apache?

Comment: Yes, Apache2 is running.

Comment: Is your apache supporting OPTIONS directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are right and problem is CORS:

Use the following directives on your apache:

```
RewriteEngine On                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Also add:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"                   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
```

While using CORS request, your server will be asked to answer to OPTIONS requests by your browser. If you do non condigure it for a correct answer, the "preflight" check will fail.

If it works you can restrict origins.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Gonna check this on monday, would be great if its working!

Comment: Worked, but now Google throws a 404. Wtf? :D

Comment: What does it mean that Google throws a 404?